# What are the zpool create -O file-system-property arguments used for?

Tags: zfs

The [man zpool create](https://zfsonlinux.org/manpages/0.8.4/man8/zpool.8.html) page states

> **-O file-system-property** = value
>   Sets the given file system properties in the root file system of the pool. See the Sx Properties section of zfs(8) for a list of valid properties that can be set.

Searching the [man zfs](https://zfsonlinux.org/manpages/0.8.4/man8/zfs.8.html) page for `Sx Properties` leads me to

> set property = value [property = value ... ] filesystem | volume | snapshot ...
>
> Sets the property or list of properties to the given value(s) for each dataset.
>       Only some properties can be edited. See the Sx Properties section for more information on what properties can be set and acceptable values.
>       [...]

I saw this on the [alpinelinux](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_with_root_on_ZFS_with_native_encryption) wiki when I was looking for how to do something similar on ubuntu 18.04 with zfs 0.8.4 (self-built).

What do the big-O options actually do?

I have experimented and created a new pool with `-O compression=lz4` and tested a few hypotheses of what they might do, but:

- `zfs get compression tank` does not show that compression is enabled
- `zfs create tank/ds` does not create a dataset with compression activated by default.

So **what do the file-system-property arguments to zpool create actually impact?**

---

#### Edit

I have tried again and this time everything behaved as I expected.

Creating a pool with `-O compression=lz4` does have the effect that `zfs get compression mypool` shows `lz4`. And it is inherited to future created child datasets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be doing what you expect, or at least it does for me. Did you do zpool create with -d, perchance, or created the pool with version below 5000 (disables all feature flags)? For compression=lz4 to work you have to have feature@lz4_compress feature flag enabled.

Comment: I have now tried to reproduce this behaviour again, after rebuilding zfs for other reasons, and now it is behaving as I expected it would. I guess I'll have to write this off to black magic or me doing something wrong. Thank you